# Checkbox checked/unchecked - get the current state

Tags: javascript

In my component page, I have couple of checkboxes so the user can check/uncheck the checkbox and save the selections.... all is good and the code below works fine.

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle"
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
....
....
<lightning-input data-id="toggle10" type="toggle"
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
mycheckboxSelection = {};
changeToggle(event) {
        this.mycheckboxSelection[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;
}
```

Issue found:

The issue I found is that if the user change the mind after toggle the checkbox the code in `changeToggle` still adds to the object.

My question:

How can I only add to the object that something has really changed?
for an example:

```
checkbox1: checked
checkbox2: checked
checkbox3: checked
```

before saving I changed my mind and uncheck the `checkbox1`

so technically I should only have `checkbox2` and `checkbox3`

but in my case I'm getting all three `checkbox1/2/3`

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote an answer about this, I think, but I can't find it. Fortunately, I still have the [source code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/8y0PZ3u78WNhfWGN4gGw/src/app.js?p=stories) for it. To know what was before, you should store a copy of the data in memory.

```
hasBeenModified = false
data  // Live modified data
original // Original data
modifiedValues // Calculated modified values
// ... more ...

handleChange(event) {
  // Update live data
  this.data[event.target.dataset.field] = event.target.checked
  // Any changes (optional, really)
  this.hasBeenModified = Object.keys(this.data).some((field) => this.data[field] !== this.original[field])
  // Calculate diff between original and data, output to modifiedValues
  this.modifiedValues = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(this.data)
      .filter(([key, value]) => this.original[key] !== value)
  )
}
```

You can feel free to see it in action in the link above.

I also wrote a [second example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/NEKUhP3zWPLWsyxF4qFq/src/app.css?p=stories) with a "save" button; this effectively reset the delta changes so that future changes would be tracked independently.

```
export default class InputTable extends LightningElement {
    displayList = false;    
    listOfAccounts = [{ index: 0, rowNumber: 1, Name: '', Email: '', Phone: '' }]
    copyDetails = [];

    createRow() {
      this.listOfAccounts = [...this.listOfAccounts, { Name: '', Email: '', Phone: '' }];
      this.reindex();
    }    
    reindex() {
      this.listOfAccounts = this.listOfAccounts.map((value,index) => ({...value, index, rowNumber: index+1 }));
      this.copyDetails = this.copyDetails.map((value,index) => ({...value, index, rowNumber: index+1 }));
    }
     // Adds a new row     
    addNewRow() {
        this.createRow();
        this.reindex();
    }    
     //Removes the selected row
     
    removeRow(event) {
      this.listOfAccounts.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
      this.reindex();
      if(!this.listOfAccounts.length) {
        this.createRow();
      }
    }
    removeCopyRow(event) {
      this.copyDetails.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
      this.reindex();
      this.displayList = !!this.copyDetails.length;
    }
     // Removes all rows     
    removeAllRows() {
      this.listOfAccounts = [];
      this.createRow();
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
      const { index, field } = event.target.dataset;
      const value = event.target.value;
      this.listOfAccounts[index][field] = value;
      this.listOfAccounts = [...this.listOfAccounts];
    }

    createRecord() {
        this.copyDetails = this.copyDetails.concat(this.listOfAccounts);
        this.displayList = true;
        this.listOfAccounts = [];
        this.createRow();
        console.log('final method');        
    }
}
```

This one also adds the ability to delete and add rows, etc, and is actually a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks as always, one quick question if I want to remove the property name (event.target.name) how would I do that?

Comment: @NickKahn you can use whatever attribute you want. I just use name.